# Laravel logging levels numeric values

Tags: laravel, logging, levels

I have seen that Laravel logging levels have specific numerical values in addition to the name, as follow:

```
'emergency' => 100
'alert'     => 200
'critical'  => 300
'error'     => 400
'warning'   => 500
'notice'    => 600
'info'      => 700
'debug'     => 800
```

Why are those values expressed in the order of houndres instead of units (i.e.: 8-1)?
Does those values comes from a convention/rfc/iso/standard?
Are those value actually used by Laravel?
Is it possible that other values are generated by some special logging event?

Comment: i couldnt found this in laravel vendor source code where are these?

Comment: @Abilogos i followed [this](https://medium.com/@alucard001/laravel-6-custom-logging-to-mysql-database-step-by-step-hand-holding-50e07bdcbb65) tutorial on making a custom mysql logger, then in my custom handler class i logged the `$record` array it is passed and i can confirm those numeric values

Comment: are you sure they are not 100,200,250,300,400,500,550,600 ?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel`s **Logger Interface** follows PSR-3 Compliment and are based on **RFC 5424** Log Levels.

> The LoggerInterface exposes eight methods to write logs to the eight
> RFC 5424 levels (debug, info, notice, warning, error, critical, alert,
> emergency).

from laravel source code:

```
<?php

namespace Psr\Log;

/**
 * Describes log levels.
 */
class LogLevel
{
    const EMERGENCY = 'emergency';
    const ALERT     = 'alert';
    const CRITICAL  = 'critical';
    const ERROR     = 'error';
    const WARNING   = 'warning';
    const NOTICE    = 'notice';
    const INFO      = 'info';
    const DEBUG     = 'debug';
}
```

RFC5424 is for system programs, **not php** . and PSR (PHP Standard Recommendation) article #3 suppose to use just **Levels** . not priorities (numbers).

and Laravel has this interface implementing and promoise to work with every library needs to log with PSR-3 compliment Log Interface.

> Note that : PSR-3 only promises Log Names (8 levels) and not priority
> numbers

Also Laravel Uses Underlying Drivers and packages for logging.

**MonoLog** is the package laravel is using to log.

it has its own api definition like priorities and codes as below:

```
/**
 * Detailed debug information
 */
const DEBUG = 100;

/**
 * Interesting events
 *
 * Examples: User logs in, SQL logs.
 */
const INFO = 200;

/**
 * Uncommon events
 */
const NOTICE = 250;

/**
 * Exceptional occurrences that are not errors
 *
 * Examples: Use of deprecated APIs, poor use of an API,
 * undesirable things that are not necessarily wrong.
 */
const WARNING = 300;

/**
 * Runtime errors
 */
const ERROR = 400;

/**
 * Critical conditions
 *
 * Example: Application component unavailable, unexpected exception.
 */
const CRITICAL = 500;

/**
 * Action must be taken immediately
 *
 * Example: Entire website down, database unavailable, etc.
 * This should trigger the SMS alerts and wake you up.
 */
const ALERT = 550;

/**
 * Urgent alert.
 */
const EMERGENCY = 600;
```

and laravel Converts PSR-3 Log Levels (names) to **Monolog Code levels**

```
/**
     * Converts PSR-3 levels to Monolog ones if necessary
     *
     * @param string|int Level number (monolog) or name (PSR-3)
     * @return int
     */
    public static function toMonologLevel($level)
    {
        if (is_string($level)) {
            // Contains chars of all log levels and avoids using strtoupper() which may have
            // strange results depending on locale (for example, "i" will become "İ")
            $upper = strtr($level, 'abcdefgilmnortuwy', 'ABCDEFGILMNORTUWY');
            if (defined(__CLASS__.'::'.$upper)) {
                return constant(__CLASS__ . '::' . $upper);
            }
         }
      return $level;
  }
```

and this is **MONOLOG** API 2:

https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Logger.php

> RFC 5424, Numbers are only for **SysLog**